# error messages in C++: function / variable "was not declared in this scope", variable "is private"

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I am new to programming in general and to C++ in particular and I am trying to set up a programme in Code::Blocks for a car dealer. It should be possible to buy and sell vehicles and to print out information about the cars. The different vehicles are all separated into different classes. In the main function I implemented an interface with a selection menu for possible actions like selling a car.

I keep getting error messages that I don`t understand (like "was not declared in this scope"), although I have already declared the functions / variables in header files (watercraftType.h, watercraft.h, amphibian.h, motorbike.h, car.h, vehicle.h, vehicleDealer.h) and included those in the respective source files and the main function (as needed).

I am getting the following error messages:

> error messages in watercraft.h:  "double Watercraft:maxdepth" is
>   private; "WatercraftType::type" is private
>
> error message in car.h:  "int Car::doors" is private

I don`t understand why the error messages show up during the
declaration of the variables in watercraft.h. In car.h the error
message shows up during the declaration of the class constructor.

> error messages in amphibian.cpp: "catchYear" was not declared in this
>   scope; "AVC", "WATERJET", "PROPELLER" was not declared in this scope

I have included the header "vehicle.h", which includes the declaration
for catchYear(), and the header "amphibian.h" in the file, which
includes the header "watercraft.h". "watercraft.h" includes
"watercraftType.h" with the declaration of the enum class
WatercraftType.

> error messages in main.cpp: in case 2: "Motorbike", "Motorrad1" was
>   not declared in this scope; expected type-specifier before
>   "Motorbike"; in case 3 for: cin >> vType;: no match for "operator>>"
>   (operand types are "std::istream {aka std:basic_istream}" and
>   "WatercraftType")

I don`t understand why I am getting these error messages, because I am
using the exact same syntax as with the class Car in case 1.

```
//vehicle.h
#ifndef VEHICLE_H_INCLUDED
#define VEHICLE_H_INCLUDED
#include <string>

class Vehicle
{
    public:
        std::string id;
        std::string model;
        virtual ~Vehicle();
        virtual void printVehicle();
        static bool checkID(std::string vId);
        int catchYear();

    private:
        int year;

    protected:
        Vehicle(std::string vId, std::string vModel, int vYear);
};

#endif // VEHICLE_H_INCLUDED



//car.h
#ifndef CAR_H_INCLUDED
#define CAR_H_INCLUDED
#include "vehicle.h"
#include <string>

class Car : public Vehicle
{
        public:
            Car(std::string vId, std::string vModel, int vYear, int vDoors, bool vRightHandDrive);
            void printVehicle();

        private:
            int doors;
            bool rightHandDrive;
};

#endif // CAR_H_INCLUDED



//watercraft.h
#ifndef WATERCRAFT_H_INCLUDED
#define WATERCRAFT_H_INCLUDED
#include "watercraftType.h"

class Watercraft
{
    private:
        double maxdepth;
        WatercraftType type;

    protected:
        Watercraft(double vMaxdepth, WatercraftType vType);
        void printVehicle();
};

#endif // WATERCRAFT_H_INCLUDED



//watercraftType.h
#ifndef WATERCRAFTTYPE_H_INCLUDED
#define WATERCRAFTTYPE_H_INCLUDED

enum class WatercraftType {AVC, WATERJET, PROPELLER};

#endif // WATERCRAFTTYPE_H_INCLUDED



//amphibian.h
#ifndef AMPHIBIAN_H_INCLUDED
#define AMPHIBIAN_H_INCLUDED
#include "car.h"
#include "watercraft.h"

class Amphibian : public Car, public Watercraft
{
    public:
        Amphibian(std::string vId, std::string vModel, int vYear, int vDoors, double vMaxdepth, WatercraftType vType);
        void printVehicle();
};

#endif // AMPHIBIAN_H_INCLUDED



//amphibian.cpp
#include "amphibian.h"
#include "vehicle.h"
#include <iostream>

//Amphibian Konstruktor
Amphibian::Amphibian(std::string vId, std::string vModel, int vYear, int vDoors, double vMaxdepth, WatercraftType vType) :
            Car(vId, vModel, vYear, vDoors, false),
            Watercraft(vMaxdepth, vType)
            {}

//Methode printVehicle
void Amphibian::printVehicle()
{
    std::cout << "Id: " << id << "\n";
    std::cout << "Model: " << model << "\n";
    std::cout << "Year: " << std::to_string(catchYear()) << "\n";
    std::cout << "Doors: " << std::to_string(doors)<< "\n";
    std::cout << "MaxDepth: " << std::to_string(maxdepth) << "\n";
    switch(type)
    {
            case AVC:           std::cout << "Type: " << "AVC" << "\n";                 break;
            case WATERJET:      std::cout << "Type: " << "WATERJET" << "\n";            break;
            case PROPELLER:     std::cout << "Type: " << "PROPELLER" << "\n";           break;
            default:            std::cout << "Type: Unknown WatercraftType" << "\n";
    }
}



//main.cpp
#include "vehicle.h"
#include "car.h"
#include "motorbike.h"
#include "amphibian.h"
#include "vehicleDealer.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    while (true)
    {
        VehicleDealer Haendler ("Dealer");
        int auswahl;

        cout << "Willkommen beim Autohändler: " << Haendler.name << ".\n"
                "Was möchten Sie tun?\n"
                "Drücken Sie die entsprechende Zahl auf der Tastatur.\n"
                "1 - Auto hinzufügen.\n"
                "2 - Motorrad hinzufügen.\n"
                "3 - Amphibienfahrzeug hinzufügen.\n"
                "4 - Fahrzeug entfernen.\n"
                "5 - Fahrzeuge anzeigen.\n"
                "Sonstige Einzelzahl: Autohändler verlassen.\n";
        cin >> auswahl;

        switch(auswahl)
        {
            case 1:
                {
                string vId;
                string vModel;
                int vYear;
                int vDoors;
                bool vRightHandDrive;
                cout << "Bitte geben Sie die nötigen Paramter zur Erstellung eines Autos ein.\n"
                "Bitte geben Sie die Fahrzeugnummer (7-stellig) ein.\n";
                cin >> vId;
                if (Vehicle::checkID(vId) == false)
                    {
                        cout << "Die Nummer ist falsch. Bitte geben Sie die Fahrzeugnummer (7-stellig) erneut ein.\n";
                        cin >> vId;
                    }
                cout << "Bitte geben Sie die Modellbezeichnung ein.\n";
                cin >> vModel;
                cout << "Bitte geben Sie die Anzahl der Türen ein.\n";
                cin >> vDoors;
                cout << "Bitte geben Sie das Herstellungsjahr des Autos ein.\n";
                cin >> vYear;
                cout << "Bitte geben Sie an, ob es sich bei dem Auto um einen Rechtslenker handelt.\n";
                cin >> vRightHandDrive;
                Car* Auto1;
                Auto1 = new Car(vId, vModel, vYear, vDoors, vRightHandDrive);
                if (Haendler.buyVehicle((Vehicle*)Auto1) == false)
                    {
                    cout << "Das Auto konnte nicht hinzugefügt werden.\n";
                    }
                break;
                }

            case 2:
                {
                string vId;
                string vModel;
                int vYear;
                cout << "Bitte geben Sie die nötigen Paramter zur Erstellung eines Motorrads ein.\n"
                "Bitte geben Sie die Fahrzeugnummer (7-stellig) ein.\n";
                cin >> vId;
                if (Vehicle::checkID(vId) == false)
                    {
                        cout << "Die Nummer ist falsch. Bitte geben Sie die Fahrzeugnummer (7-stellig) erneut ein.\n";
                        cin >> vId;
                    }
                cout << "Bitte geben Sie die Modellbezeichnung ein.\n";
                cin >> vModel;
                cout << "Bitte geben Sie das Herstellungsjahr des Motorrads ein.\n";
                cin >> vYear;
                Motorbike* Motorrad1;
                Motorrad1 = new Motorbike(vId, vModel, vYear);
                if (Haendler.buyVehicle((Vehicle*)Motorrad1) == false)
                    {
                    cout << "Das Motorrad konnte nicht hinzugefügt werden.\n";
                    }
                break;
                }

            case 3:
                {
                string vId;
                string vModel;
                int vYear;
                int vDoors;
                double vMaxdepth;
                WatercraftType vType;
                cout << "Bitte geben Sie die nötigen Paramter zur Erstellung eines Amphibienfahrzeugs ein.\n"
                "Bitte geben Sie die Fahrzeugnummer (7-stellig) ein.\n";
                cin >> vId;
                if (Vehicle::checkID(vId) == false)
                    {
                        cout << "Die Nummer ist falsch. Bitte geben Sie die Fahrzeugnummer (7-stellig) erneut ein.\n";
                        cin >> vId;
                    }
                cout << "Bitte geben Sie die Modellbezeichnung ein.\n";
                cin >> vModel;
                cout << "Bitte geben Sie das Herstellungsjahr des Amphibienfahrzeugs ein.\n";
                cin >> vYear;
                cout << "Bitte geben Sie die Anzahl der Türen ein.\n";
                cin >> vDoors;
                cout << "Bitte geben Sie die maximale Tiefe als Gleitkommazahl (mit Punkt) an.\n";
                cin >> vMaxdepth;
                cout << "Bitte geben Sie den Antriebstyp an (AVC, WATERJET, PROPELLER).\n";
                cin >> vType;
                Amphibian* Amphibian1;
                Amphibian1 = new Amphibian(vId, vModel, vYear, vDoors, vMaxdepth, vType);
                if (Haendler.buyVehicle((Vehicle*)Amphibian1) == false)
                    {
                    cout << "Das Amphibienfahrzeug konnte nicht hinzugefügt werden.\n";
                    }
                break;
                }

            case 4:
                {
                string vId;
                cout << "Bitte geben Sie die Fahrzeugnummer (7-stellig) des Fahrzeugs ein, das Sie entfernen wollen.\n";
                cin >> vId;
                if (Haendler.sellVehicle(vId) == false)
                    {
                    cout << "Das Fahrzeug konnte nicht entfernt werden.\n";
                    }
                break;
                }

            case 5:
                {
                cout << "Alle vorhandenen Fahrzeuge werden ausgegeben.\n";
                Haendler.printVehicles();
                break;
                }

            default:
                {
                cout << "Sie haben eine sonstige Ziffer gewählt. Das Programm wird beendet.\n";
                return 0;
                }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'll bet you could remove at least 90% of that code and still get the error.

Comment: @Brabrara Where is the variable doors used in this statement  std::cout << "Doors: " << std::to_string(doors)<< "\n"; declared? Is it a private data member of the class Car? If so then you may not use it in this context.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access  Watercraft:maxdepth and WatercraftType::type because you've declared them private. In order to use them in your Amphibian class you need to declare them public or private.

To fix your error in Amphibian::printVehicle() you need to write

```
`void Amphibian::printVehicle()
{
    std::cout << "Id: " << id << "\n";
    std::cout << "Model: " << model << "\n";
    std::cout << "Year: " << std::to_string(catchYear()) << "\n";
    std::cout << "Doors: " << std::to_string(doors)<< "\n";
    std::cout << "MaxDepth: " << std::to_string(maxdepth) << "\n";
    switch(type)
    {
            case WatercraftType::AVC:           std::cout << "Type: " << "AVC" << "\n";                 break;
            case WatercraftType::WATERJET:      std::cout << "Type: " << "WATERJET" << "\n";            break;
            case WatercraftType::PROPELLER:     std::cout << "Type: " << "PROPELLER"<< "\n";           break;
            default:            std::cout << "Type: Unknown WatercraftType" << "\n";
    }
}`
```

You can find the fixed version here:
https://godbolt.org/z/RF-Kqi